# Cron with REST interface?

Tags: cron

I need a cron-like tool that supports REST API. It should have all the features of cron + the ability to read (and maybe even write) new cron rules.

I've scoured the interwebs but found nothing mature. and yes, I realize that REST interface for cron could be a serious security issue.

[minicron](https://github.com/jamesrwhite/minicron) does not offer REST API at the moment

[chronos](http://nerds.airbnb.com/introducing-chronos/) is way too overblown for my purposes (its built on top of ZooKeeper and Mesos)

this [rest-cron](https://github.com/EHER/rest-cron/blob/master/controllers.py) project is abandoned and only partially implemented.

[fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/download.php) lacks what I need but is opensource and could maybe be extended, but its c code which would be a pain.

[jobber](https://github.com/dshearer/jobber) is a go-based cron-like, which would be easier to modify.

Still I was hoping for an out of the box solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

To manage my infrastructure, I use EasyCron - https://www.easycron.com/document - The API isn't the most sophisticated, but gives me more control.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using [recurry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recurry) for this reason (nodejs).